# Django query filter with variable column

Tags: django

I am trying to filter a queryset using

```
info=members.filter(name__contains=search_string)
```

The problem I have is I do not know which field the user wants to search ahead of time so I need to substitute 'name' with a variable as in

```
variable_column = 'name'
search_type = 'contains'
filter = variable_column + '__' + search_type
info=members.filter(filter=search_string)
```

How do I do that?

Rich

Comment: Gotta love StackOverflow. The problem you're struggling with was solved 10 years ago XD.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Almost there..

`members.filter(**{'string__contains': 'search_string'})`

To understand what it's doing, google around  : )
[Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

`**` expands dictionary key/value pairs to keyword argument - value pairs.

To adapt your example to the solution:

```
variable_column = 'name'
search_type = 'contains'
filter = variable_column + '__' + search_type
info=members.filter(**{ filter: search_string })
```

Comment: This may be the best answer I've seen in a long time.

Comment: Or in reference to your django model:  Members_Model.objects.filter(**{ filter: search_string })

Comment: Ok, really old question, I know, but: Doesn't the use of the name filter both as the object manager method and the key in the dict cause problems?

Comment: Ok another question can this string have more than one keys and variables incorporate all variables?

Comment: @Rich @jonincanada- Searching for possibilty of using _variable_ in place of fields struck upon this nice solution. Now if I want to **pass the model name** also as a `variable`, **how would I do that**?

Answer (score -3):

**Syntax:**

```
model_name.objects.filter(column_name='value')
```

**Ex:** In my scenario, I wanted to find out all records with status completed from the Student table.

```
Student.objects.filter(status="completed")
```

Comment: this is just a standard filter, has nothign to do witht he question.