# Pass kwargs into Django Filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

When viewing model entries from within Django Admin, you can specify filters. How can I mimic this behavior? Not to familiar with `kwargs` but something similar to this:

```
foo = Model.objects.filter(**__exact='**')
```

where the first set of `**` would be a field in the model and the second set would be an entry. Basically making the queries variable, based on what the user chooses on the front end. How would I send that variable sort option to the view, and then return it back to the webpage. What about using a dictionary? Please help

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720079/django-query-filter-with-variable-column) has proven to be a little helpful, but still cannot grasp it completely.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can unpack a python dict as your filter parameters using `**`

```
your_filters = {
'field_1__exact': value_1,
'field_2__gte': value_2,
}

Model.objects.filter(**your_filters)
```

Said that, you can built your query filters(a python dict) dynamically based on an user input.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 2 questions: do the `**` apply to the `your_filters` variable letting Django know that this can change? If so, isn't that what a variable already does, it varies? Question#2: Let's say I put 'placeholders' on the front end, how could I translate the user's selection back to the view. An AJAX call perhaps?

Comment: @Kervvv about your question 2: yes, you can pass it using ajax and reading them from request.POST or request.GET data, depending what do you want. I din't understand the first question.

Comment: @levi, Is there anyway I can add "OR" statements inside the kwarg filters?

Comment: @Christopher use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects in django and pipes. `Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')`