# How to dynamically select variable data columns from variable tables when the columns and the tables are dependent on stored data?

Tags: json, django, django-models, jsonb

Using Django 1.10, Python 3.5,

I have stored various information about the columns and tables I want to use to extract data in another table called `smart_view`

That `smart_view` has the following columns:

1. id (auto increment)
2. name (varchar 255)
3. columns (jsonb type)
4. tables (jsonb type)
5. conditions (jsonb type)

I want to dynamically select data columns from tables that may vary depending on the data stored in `smart_view` table

I read about dynamically generate filters using an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4720109/80353.

Is that applicable to my situation and how do I do the same for the tables (or Model) part?

**UPDATE**

The usual way of selecting specific values is

`Entry.objects.values_list('id', 'headline')`

As seen in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

By dynamic, I meant you wouldn't know beforehand which model to extract the values from and which values they might be because they are stored as data in the table called `smart_view`

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do. What do you mean by "dynamically"? What is dynamic here?

Comment: updated with an example. thanks @DanielRoseman

Comment: That isn't really an example. What do you want to output? And note that that is **not** the usual way of creating a queryset; that is the way of creating a values list, which is a very restricted usage of queries with extremely limited usefulness.

Comment: Okay I have rephrased my question. Nothing to do with queryset directly. Have I sufficiently made this question clearer about what I am looking for?