# Another way to query JSONField in postgresql django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have made Django project with the database on PostgreSQL. I have one column data which is a JSONField() object. Now for querying in the data JSON blob, the docs show only one way. Say some rows have the key as 'Salary' in data so according to docs if I want to retrieve the row with salary as something then the way is:

```
TableName.objects.filter(data__Salary__gte = 15000)
```

Now the problem is that I want to make it user specific like the user will tell the key and pass it to the function and I want something like this:

```
keyValue = 'Salary'
TableName.objects.filter(data__keyValue__gte = 15000)
```

But this does not work for obvious reasons as there is no column of keyValue in data. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: possibly duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720079/django-query-filter-with-variable-column).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary and unpack it in the `filter` call using the `**` operator.

```py
>>> key_value = 'Salary'
>>>
>>> params = {'data__%s__gte' % key_value:15000}
>>> TableName.objects.filter(**params)
```